# Regex that can match empty string is breaking the javascript regex engine

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote the following regex: `/\D(?!.*\D)|^-?|\d+/g`

I think it should work this way:

```
\D(?!.*\D)    # match the last non-digit
|             # or
^-?           # match the start of the string with optional literal '-' character
|             # or
\d+           # match digits
```

But, it doesn't:

```js
var arrTest = '12,345,678.90'.match(/\D(?!.*\D)|^-?|\d+/g);
console.log(arrTest);

var test = arrTest.join('').replace(/[^\d-]/, '.');
console.log(test);
```

However, when playing it with *`PCRE(php)`-flavour* online at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xP9lN3/1). It works as I described.

I don't know if I think it should work one way it doesn't work. Or if there are some pattern not allowed in javascript regex-flavour.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @anubhava. I want it to return `12345678.90`

Comment: I think you can use `var res = '-12,345,678.90'.replace(/(\D)(?!.*\D)|^-?|\D/g, function($0,$1) {
   return $1 ? "." : "";
});` - a single replace operation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Man, this is smart, you are doing all inside only one replace method and works

Comment: JS works differently than PCRE. The point is that the JS regex engine does not handle zero-length matches well, the index is just manually incremented and the next character after a zero-length match is skipped.

Comment: Thank you both, I upvoted your answers

Comment: @Guedes: I added an excerpt from ECMA reference that actually documents that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS works differently than PCRE. The point is that the JS regex engine does not handle zero-length matches well, the index is just manually incremented and the next character after a zero-length match is skipped. The `^-?` can match an empty string, and it matches the `12,345,678.90` start, skipping `1`.

If we have a look at the [`String#match` documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10), we will see that each call to `match` with a global regex increases the regex object's `lastIndex` after the *zero-length* match is found:

> 8. Else, *global* is **true**
>      a. Call the [[Put]] internal method of rx with arguments "**lastIndex**" and 0.
>      b. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression **new Array()** where **Array** is the standard built-in constructor with that name.
>      c. Let *previousLastIndex* be 0.
>      d. Let *n* be 0.
>      e. Let *lastMatch* be **true**.
>      f. Repeat, while *lastMatch* is **true**
>          i. Let *result* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of *exec* with *rx* as the **this** value and argument list containing *S*.
>          ii. If *result* is **null**, then set *lastMatch* to **false**.
>          iii. Else, *result* is not **null**
>              1. Let *thisIndex* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *rx* with argument "**lastIndex**".
>              2. If *thisIndex = previousLastIndex* then
>                  a. Call the [[Put]] internal method of *rx* with arguments "**lastIndex**" and *thisIndex+1*.
>                  b. Set *previousLastIndex* to *thisIndex*+1.

So, the matching process goes from *8a* till *8f* initializing the auxiliary structures, then a while block is entered (repeated until *lastMatch* is **true**, an internal *exec* command matches the empty space at the start of the string (*8fi* -> *8fiii*), and as the result is not **null**, *thisIndex* is set to the *lastIndex* of the previous successful match, and as the match was zero-length (basically, *thisIndex* = *previousLastIndex*), the *previousLastIndex* is set to *thisIndex+1* - **which is skipping the current position after a successful zero-length match**.

You may actually use a simpler regex inside a `replace` method and use a callback to use appropriate replacements:

```js
var res = '-12,345,678.90'.replace(/(\D)(?!.*\D)|^-|\D/g, function($0,$1) {
   return $1 ? "." : "";
});
console.log(res);
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(\D)(?!.*\D)` - a non-digit (captured into Group 1) that is not followed with 0+ chars other than a newline and another non-digit
- `|` - or
- `^-` - a hyphen at the string start
- `|` - or
- `\D` - a non-digit

Note that here you do not even have to make the hyphen at the start optional.

Comment: Took me 16 minutes to add (and format) the ECMA reference with step-by-step explanation why this happens. Hope it explains this weird JS *global* regex matching behavior. Note that PCRE just does not bluntly increments the position after a zero-length match, it re-checks the next character correctly.

Comment: Thanks :) ... I ended up with `.replace(/(^-)|\D(?=.*\D)|(\D)/g, function($0, $1, $2) { return $1 || ($2 ? '.' : ''); });` to avoid replacing the negative sign.

Comment: If you do not need to replace that minus, why use the alternative branch at all :) ? Just remove the `(^-)|` from the pattern and remove `$2` from the callback function and adjust its body.

Answer (score 2):

You can reorder your alternation patterns and use this in JS to make it work:

```js
var arrTest = '12,345,678.90'.match(/\D(?!.*\D)|\d+|^-?/g);
console.log(arrTest);

var test = arrTest.join('').replace(/\D/, '.');

console.log(test);

//=> 12345678.90
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xP9lN3/2)

This is the difference between Javascript and PHP(PCRE) regex behavior.

In Javascript:

```
'12345'.match(/^|.+/gm)
//=> ["", "2345"]
```

**In PHP:**

```
preg_match_all('/^|.+/m', '12345', $m);
print_r($m);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] => 12345
        )
    )
```

So when you match `^` in Javascript, regex engine moves one position ahead and anything after alternation `|` matches from 2nd position omwards in input.

Comment: It is because when you match `^` in JS regex engine moves one position ahead and anything after alternation `|` matches from 2nd position in input. Test with `'12345'.match(/^|.+/gm)` which will give `["", "2345"]`