# Perl vs Javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, pcre

Why does the following regex capture (via the capturing group) the string 'abc' in Javascript, but not in PCRE (although it will still match)?

`(.*)*`

Comment: You must be confused with the regex101.com way of highlighting capturing groups, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Don't think that's it. Compare the contents of the capture group between [the JavaScript version](https://regex101.com/r/zLg7UG/1) and [the PCRE version](https://regex101.com/r/zLg7UG/2). The former shows "abc", the latter shows empty. (Unless you meant a bug in regex101. The explanations appear to be identical despite the results being different.)

Comment: In fact, the canonical case is `(.*)*`. Putting the kleene star on the end stops the capture group from working, with PCRE. At least, according to regex101 it does. Am I missing something with this particular regex tester?

Comment: Also, if I change the * to +, i.e. `(.+)+` it works how I expect it would.

Comment: Ok, https://ideone.com/ALeMqh and https://jsfiddle.net/wvudw7yv/ show the same. Must be the difference related to empty match handling in JS and PCRE. Yes, changing `*` to `+` makes the pattern match at least 1 char. This question is in line with many others, and their root cause is the way empty matches are handled with JS regex. See [**Some regex pattern is breaking the javascript regex engine**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860487/some-regex-pattern-is-breaking-the-javascript-regex-engine/38860774#38860774).

Comment: I understand the point that this regex can match the empty string, but the part I don't get is that given a _non-empty string_, perl will match the whole thing, but _not capture_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's why the capture group is empty in PCRE:

- Initial state

  ```
  (.*)*     abc
   ^        ^
  ```
- First, the `(.*)` part is matched against `abc`, and the input position is advanced to the end. The capture group contains `abc` at this point.

  ```
  (.*)*     abc
      ^        ^
  ```
- Now, the input position is *after* the `c` character, the remaining input is the empty string. The Kleene star initiates a second attempt at matching the `(.*)` group:

  ```
  (.*)*     abc
   ^           ^
  ```
- The `(.*)` group matches the *empty string* after `abc`. Since it matched, **the previously captured string is overwritten**.
- Since the input position hasn't advanced, the `*` ends iterating there and the match succeeds.

The behavior difference between JS and PCRE is due to the way the regex engines are specified. PCRE's behavior is consistent with Perl:

PCRE:

```
$ pcretest
PCRE version 8.39 2016-06-14

  re> /(.*)*/
data> abc
 0: abc
 1:
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -e '"abc" =~ /(.*)*/; print "<$&> <$1>\n";'
<abc> <>
```

Let's [compare this with .NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.*%29*&i=abc), which has the same behavior, but *supports multiple captures*:

[image: .NET regex]

When a capture group is matched for a second time, .NET will add the captured value to a *capture stack*. Perl and PCRE will simply overwrite it.

---

As for JavaScript:

Here's [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) §21.2.2.5.1 Runtime Semantics: RepeatMatcher Abstract Operation:

> The abstract operation *RepeatMatcher* takes eight parameters, a Matcher `m`, an integer `min`, an integer (or ∞) `max`, a Boolean `greedy`, a State `x`, a Continuation `c`, an integer `parenIndex`, and an integer `parenCount`, and performs the following steps:
>
> 1. If `max` is zero, return `c(x)`.
> 2. Create an internal Continuation closure `d` that takes one State argument `y` and performs the following steps when evaluated:
>
>    - a. If `min` is zero and `y`'s `endIndex` is equal to `x`'s `endIndex`, return `failure`.
>    - b. If `min` is zero, let `min2` be zero; otherwise let `min2` be `min‑1`.
>    - c. If `max` is ∞, let `max2` be ∞; otherwise let `max2` be `max‑1`.
>    - d. Call `RepeatMatcher(m, min2, max2, greedy, y, c, parenIndex, parenCount)` and return its result.
> 3. Let `cap` be a fresh copy of `x`'s captures List.
> 4. For every integer `k` that satisfies `parenIndex < k` and `k ≤ parenIndex+parenCount`, set `cap[k]` to `undefined`.
> 5. Let `e` be `x`'s endIndex.
> 6. Let `xr` be the State `(e, cap)`.
> 7. If `min` is not zero, return `m(xr, d)`.
> 8. If `greedy` is `false`, then
>
>    - a. Call `c(x)` and let `z` be its result.
>    - b. If `z` is not `failure`, return `z`.
>    - c. Call `m(xr, d)` and return its result.
> 9. Call `m(xr, d)` and let `z` be its result.
> 10. If `z` is not `failure`, return `z`.
> 11. Call `c(x)` and return its result.

This is basically the definition of what's supposed to be happening when a quantifier is evaluated. `RepeatMatcher` is the operation handling the matching of an inner operation `m`.

You'll also need to understand what a *State* is (§21.2.2.1, emphasis mine):

> A State is an ordered pair (`endIndex`, `captures`) where `endIndex` is an integer and captures is a List of `NcapturingParens` values. States are used to represent partial match states in the regular expression matching algorithms. **The `endIndex` is one plus the index of the last input character matched so far by the pattern**, while `captures` holds the results of capturing parentheses. The `n`th element of `captures` is either a List that represents the value obtained by the `n`th set of capturing parentheses or undefined if the `n`th set of capturing parentheses hasn't been reached yet. Due to backtracking, many 
>   States may be in use at any time during the matching process.

For your example, the `RepeatMatcher` parameters are:

- `m`: the *Matcher* responsible for handling the subpattern `(.*)`
- `min`: 0 (minimum number of matches for the Kleene star quantifier)
- `max`: ∞ (maximum number of matches for the Kleene star quantifier)
- `greedy`: true (the Kleene star quantifier used is greedy)
- `x`: `(0, [undefined])` (see the state definition above)
- `c`: The continuation, at this point it'll be: *a Continuation that always returns its State argument as a successful `MatchResult`*, after collapsing the parent rules
- `parenIndex`: 0 (as per §21.2.2.5 this is the *number of left capturing parentheses in the entire regular expression that occur to the left of this
  production*)
- `parenCount`: 1 (same spec paragraph, this is *the number of left capturing parentheses in the expansion of this production's Atom* - I won't paste the full spec here but this basically means that `m` defines one capture group)

The regex matching algorithm in the spec is defined in terms of [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Basically, this means that the `c` operation means *what should happen next*.

Let's unroll this algorithm.

### First iteration

On the first pass, the `x`<sub>1</sub> state is `(0, [undefined])`.

1. `max` is not zero
2. We create the continuation closure `d`<sub>1</sub> at this point, it'll be used in the second pass so we'll come back to this one later.
3. Make a copy `cap`<sub>1</sub> of the capture list
4. Reset the capture in `cap`<sub>1</sub> to `undefined`, this is a no-op in the fist pass
5. Let `e`<sub>1</sub> = 0
6. Let `xr`<sub>1</sub> = (`e`<sub>1</sub>, `cap`<sub>1</sub>)
7. `min` is zero, skip this step
8. `greedy` is true, skip this step
9. Let `z`<sub>1</sub> = `m`(`xr`, `d`<sub>1</sub>) - this evaluates the subpattern `(.*)`

Now let's step back a bit - `m` will match `(.*)` against `abc`, and then call our `d`<sub>1</sub> closure, so let's unroll that one.

`d`<sub>1</sub> is evaluated with the state `y`<sub>1</sub> =`(3, ["abc"])`:

- `min` is 0, but `y`<sub>1</sub>'s `endIndex` is 3 and `x`<sub>1</sub>'s `endIndex` is 0, so don't return `failure`
- Let `min2` = `min` = 0 since `min` = 0
- Let `max2` = `max` = ∞ since `max` = ∞
- Call `RepeatMatcher(m, min2, max2, greedy, y, c, parenIndex, parenCount)` and return its result. That is: RepeatMatcher(m, 0, ∞, false, y<sub>1</sub>, c, 0, 1)

### Second iteration

So, right now we're going for a second iteration with `x`<sub>2</sub> = `y`<sub>1</sub> = `(3, ["abc"])`.

1. `max` is not zero
2. We create the continuation closure `d`<sub>2</sub> at this point
3. Make a copy `cap`<sub>2</sub> of the capture list `["abc"]`
4. Reset the capture in `cap`<sub>2</sub> to `undefined`, we get `cap`<sub>2</sub> = `[undefined]`
5. Let `e`<sub>2</sub> = 3
6. Let `xr`<sub>2</sub> = (`e`<sub>2</sub>, `cap`<sub>2</sub>)
7. `min` is zero, skip this step
8. `greedy` is true, skip this step
9. Let `z`<sub>2</sub> = `m`(`xr`<sub>2</sub>, `d`<sub>2</sub>) - this evaluates the subpattern `(.*)`

   This time `m` will match the empty string after `abc`, and call our `d`<sub>2</sub> closure with that one. Let's evaluate what `d`<sub>2</sub> does. It's parameter is `y`<sub>2</sub> = `(3, [""])`

   `min` is still 0, but `y`<sub>2</sub>'s `endIndex` is 3 and `x`<sub>2</sub>'s `endIndex` is also 3 (remember that this time `x` is the `y` state from the previous iteration), the closure simply returns `failure`.
10. `z`<sub>2</sub> is `failure`, skip this step
11. return `c`(`x`<sub>2</sub>), which is `c((3, ["abc"]))` in this iteration.

`c` simply returns a valid MatchResult here as we're at the end of the pattern. Which means that `d`<sub>1</sub> returns this result, and the first iteration returns passes it along from step 10.

Basically, as you can see, the spec line which causes the JS behavior to be different than PCRE's is the following one:

> a. If `min` is zero and `y`'s `endIndex` is equal to `x`'s `endIndex`, return `failure`.

When combined with:

> 11. Call `c(x)` and return its result.

Which returns the *previously* captured values if the iteration fails.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. However, I'm not sure I understand what the JS behaviour is. Presumably, the outer * is *not* matching a second time when its subject is empty? Certainly if I use `(.*){2}` in JS and *force* a second match, the behaviour matches Perl.

Comment: @TimAngus I'd have to dig into the JS spec to find out, but I suspect JS just stops as soon as it reaches the end of the string. I didn't include it into the answer as I'm not 100% sure about that, I'll try to find out and add it later.

Comment: As for Perl, it doesn't give an endless sequence of empty strings because Perl discards a match with the same starting position and the same length as the previous match.

Comment: @ikegami hmmm I don't think the *"same length"* part matters, the rule should rather be: advance the input position to the end of the last match, and add one character if the last match was an empty string (to avoid infinite loops when you get an empty match - this is a shortcoming of the JS regex API).

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski, You are mistaken. Perl does not add one character if the last match was an empty string. For example, `perl -E'say "\@$-[0]: $&" while "abc" =~ /.*?/g'` demonstrates matching both an empty string then a non-empty string at the same position. As I said above, Perl adds one when the match is at the same position and of the same length as the preceding one.

Comment: Oops, I mispoke, Perl forces a backtrack when the match would be at the same pos and length as the last match. It only adds one to the starting position when a match couldn't be found at the current location.

Comment: @ikegami I just checked the behavior of PCRE.NET, which is the PCRE wrapper library I wrote for .NET, to make sure it's consistent with the Perl behavior on your example. Good news - it is :-) But my implementation isn't [*quite* the same](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net/blob/3ce617497c8338bda93ddbe5a354102cdc9259a3/src/PCRE.NET/PcreRegex.Match.cs#L132-L133) as what you're saying. The rule is simply to disallow an empty match if the last match was empty (other code in there handles `\K` which is quite fun by itself). I'm wondering if I could find a test case that diverges from Perl..

Comment: @ikegami ok so `(?=.\K)` makes Perl loop forever, it causes a timeout on regex101, pcretest returns 3 results along with a warning *"Start of matched string is beyond its end - displaying from end to start."*, and PCRE.NET returns 3 empty results. Looks like I've found my discrepancy, but at least I'm kind of consistent with pcretest ;)

Comment: @TimAngus I added the JS explanation - it's a bit messy but hopefully makes sense.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Excellent answer! And surprisingly complicated.

Comment: @TimAngus thanks for a surprisingly interesting question ;)