# JavaScript RegExp * in (a*|b)

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
var color = "aab";

var p1 = /(a*|b)/ig;

console.log(color.match(p1))
```

It will log ["aa", "", ""].Why it can not match 'b'?

Comment: Because it matched an empty location before `b` and skipped this symbol.  What is the actual result you are after? Or do you just need the explanation? See the explanation of how `match` works in the [Some regex pattern is breaking the javascript regex engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38860774/3832970).

Comment: Use `a*b` to match `b`, `ab`, `aab`, `aaaa...b`. Use `a+b` if string will always start with `a`.

Comment: Just FYI: you should also bear in mind that with an unanchored alternation group, the first alternative "wins" and others are not tried. `a*` matches anywhere inside a string, so `b` will never be even tested. You may "fix" it with `/(b|a*)/ig` or best, excluding the chance of matching empty strings - `/(a+|b)/ig`