# Difference between .split(/^|\s+/) and .split(/s+/)

Tags: javascript, regex, d3.js

I'm reading source code of `d3` and in [this lines](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/on.js#L35) they try split event name by words. But why are they using `^|` in 
this `^|\s+` regex? When `string.trim().split(/^|\s+/)` and `string.trim().split(/\s+/)` do they give difference results?

Comment: Well, `^|\s+` is not the same as `\s+` because `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces and `^|\s+` matches start of string *or* one or more whitespaces. Same as all other suchlike "gimme-regex-explanation" requests. All that can easily be tested at http://regex101.com. And see the explanation there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, can you give examples preferred using `^|\s+ ` instead of `\s+`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, fixed the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string does not start with whitespaces, there is no difference in `split` behavior:

```
console.log("a b c".split(/\s+/))
// => ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log("a b c".split(/^|\s+/))
// => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

If there are whitespaces at the start, the output is different:

```
console.log(" a b c".split(/^|\s+/))
// => [" a", "b", "c"]
console.log(" a b c".split(/\s+/))
// => ["", "a", "b", "c"]
```

The reason is that matching an empty string causes the JS regex engine skip the next char. It is described in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860774/3832970). So, it may be considered a "trick" to include the first space into the first array item.

Comment: but there is a trim before it `string.trim().split(/^|\s+/)`. I suppose the `.trim()` might have been added at a later point

Comment: @Slai So, there is no difference then in that code. The `split` difference with the two patterns is what OP asks about in the title.